# Xcode 6 Manual UIView Resize Issue

Tags: xcode, uiview, storyboard

Ok, so I have multiple views on one of my screens.  UIButtons, UIImageViews, UIViews, and a Container View.

Anytime I go to resize a view, it seems that one view will be auto resized to 0.  When I resize via the actual inspector, no issues.  It is just manual resizing on the storyboard itself.

I am not sure what is going on, has anyone experienced this?

[>Check a video here<](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-fVCldSFHw&list=UUUtlW6PlvxLEU6Zq-man8wg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also seeing this.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Same, this is incredibly annoying and I'm shocked that this still isn't patched in Xcode 6.2. Seems specific to UIViews that are subviews, any time you drag resize any element it immediately sets UIView subviews to 0.0.0.0 size.